# How do I change my timezone to UTC/GMT?

Tags: configuration, time, timezone

Currently when I execute the date command from bash I get the following displayed

`Thu May 17 12:21:00 IST 2012`

Below is my timezone config based on executing `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

```
  Current default time zone: 'Europe/Dublin'
  Local time is now: Thu May 17 12:32:52 IST 2012.
  Universal Time is now: Thu May 17 11:32:52 UTC 2012.
```

Any idea how I change from IST to UTC/GMT?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

> Any idea how I change from IST to GMT?

To switch to UTC, simply execute `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`, scroll to the bottom of the Continents list and select `Etc` or `None of the above`; in the second list, select `UTC`. If you prefer GMT instead of UTC, it's just above UTC in that list. :)

Comment: Yes!  I wish this was enabled by default.

Comment: After I did what you wrote above, and changed the time zone, my server is still having the same wrong time, do I need to restart the system, or what?

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04.1, `Etc` is `None of the above`.

Comment: From the command line in Ubuntu, the following link provides the trivial 1-line command: http://askubuntu.com/a/524362/182454

Comment: Simplicity! (KISS) Love it, Thanks! On a minimal Server install the other time Zones are not available, just UTC, so installing `sudo apt install tzdata` is a MUST!

Comment: This changed Local time. But the universal time does not change. My website is using the universal time.

Comment: you saved my life. for new server developer click space on keyboard to choose .

Answer (score 95):

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone UTC
```

Will change your timezone to UTC system wide.

You can do `timedatectl list-timezones` to see all the available timezones.

---

**excerpt from [@MattJohnson's answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21300212/33204)**

> Zones like `Etc/GMT+6` are intentionally reversed for backwards compatibility with POSIX standards.  See the comments in [this file](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/etcetera).
>
> You should almost never need to use these zones.  Instead you should be using a fully named time zone like `America/New_York` or `Europe/London` or whatever is appropriate for your location.  Refer to the list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Answer (score 14):

In the old Un*x style (SunOS, HPUX...), you can do:

```
ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime
```

Check the contents of /usr/share/zoneinfo to get the timezone you want/need.

For instance, Irish Summer Time (IST) can be defined as

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3661 Mar 13 22:18 /usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Eire
```

or

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Mar 13 22:18 /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Dublin -> ../posix/Eire
```

However, the most important is to use a proper clock reference and a ntp daemon (openntpd for instance), as timezone is only used for displaying/converting the time to strings, not to store it (whatever the timezone, difference to 01/01/1970 is everywhere the same on Earth).

Comment: I can use this to change UTC to Asia/Kolkatta with.. `sudo rm /etc/localtime` (i had already this file so couldn't create symlink with next command, so i deleted it first), `sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata /etc/localtime`. I think this seems to be a general solution.

Answer (score 9):

**Updated for 14.04 to present**

**View Time and Date Status:**

```
$ timedatectl status
                      Local time: Sun 2018-07-29 15:26:03 BST
                  Universal time: Sun 2018-07-29 14:26:03 UTC
                        RTC time: Sun 2018-07-29 14:26:03
                       Time zone: Europe/London (BST, +0100)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

**View List of Timezones:**
Listed Timezones (425)

```
$ timedatectl list-timezones
Africa/Abidjan
Africa/Accra
Africa/Addis_Ababa
...
Pacific/Tongatapu
Pacific/Wake
Pacific/Wallis
UTC
```

**Set Timezone to UTC:**

```
$ timedatectl set-timezone UTC
```

**View Time and Date Status:**

```
$ timedatectl status
                      Local time: Sun 2018-07-29 14:46:27 UTC
                  Universal time: Sun 2018-07-29 14:46:27 UTC
                        RTC time: Sun 2018-07-29 14:46:27
                       Time zone: UTC (UTC, +0000)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no*
```

Comment: Hey, can you help me to set timezone  UTC+06:00?? thanks

Comment: I had a dig around, but set-timezone only allows you to set a timezone in the available list-timezones, you can't apply modifiers or offsets it seems. There may be another way to achieve setting UTC+06:00 but I couldn't find it... worth asking the forum in a new question.

Comment: Hey I solved it, `sudo timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Dhaka` btw Thanks.

Comment: I misunderstood your requirement... there are numerous timezones in the available list-timezones set that meet the UTC+06:00, I thought you were looking for a way of applying a non-geographic generic UTC offset. Glad you found what you were looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
$ date
Wed Jul 16 22:52:47 EDT 2014

$ cat /etc/timezone
America/New_York

$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
$ service cron stop && service cron start
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you need this for only a single command, say, `ls`, use this:

```
TZ=UTC ls -l --full-time
```