# Running timedatectl but it's not updating the system time zone

Tags: time

I'm trying to set the system time to UTC such that when I log in and run `date`, or run programs that ask for the current time (say, `python -c 'import datetime; print datetime.datetime.now()'`), they return times in UTC. Based on searching and https://askubuntu.com/a/524362, I expect that when I run

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone UTC
```

the system time will be set to UTC. That program exits with 0 when I run it and `timedatectl status` prints the following output:

```
$ timedatectl status
      Local time: Wed 2016-03-16 14:31:50 UTC
  Universal time: Wed 2016-03-16 14:31:50 UTC
        RTC time: Wed 2016-03-16 14:31:49
       Time zone: UTC (UTC, +0000)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

However, when I log out, log back in, and run `date`, I still get a value in EDT:

```
$ date
Wed Mar 16 10:31:32 EDT 2016
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it might be because of the automatic time setting. I'm not very experienced in this though.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind getting an interactive application,

`$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`.

As to why the `timedatectl` failed, see the GUI time/date configuration option in System Settings. It is possible that some `Use network time` setting is blocking it.

Another alternative method is:

`$ sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/GMT$offset /etc/localtime`,
where `$offset` is the offset from GMT(UTC) time. Since, you want UTC,

`$ sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/GMT /etc/localtime`.