# Set environment variable globally

Tags: bash, performance, environment-variables

I recently saw this blog post regarding performance when the TZ environment variable is not set:
https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2017/02/21/set-environment-variable-save-thousands-of-system-calls/

I have noticed this problem when stracing running daemons on my systems and would like to fix it. I reviewed the official Ubuntu documentation for where to define environment variables:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

I tried defining TZ in /etc/environment and in /etc/profile.d/test.sh, but I cannot get this environment variable to be available in all cases (e.g. if I just execute bash without --login or if I run the sample c program provided in the above article). How can I make the TZ environment variable defined completely system-wide?

Thanks!

---

Edit: It was suggested that my question is a duplicate of [this other post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323131), but the methods described in that post do not solve this problem. I tried both of these: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` and `sudo timedatectl set-timezone America/New_York`. After, I confirmed that /etc/localtime is a valid symlink as expected. However, after a reboot I still see 10 stat() calls to /etc/localtime as documented in the original article I posted above. The behavior I am looking for (as documented in the original article) is making it so /etc/localtime is not stat()-ed repeatedly, which is very inefficient

Comment: Did you log out (of the desktop session) and back in after modifying /etc/environment or /etc/profile.d/xxx? AFAIK those changes should propagate down from the shell that's started by the display manager

Comment: Yes, I rebooted. Note that I want this variable to be available from services started via upstart or systemd, which could execute with /bin/sh or another shell (not bash) and thus may not read in /etc/profile.d/*

Comment: I'm only scratching the surface with systemd, but as far as I can make out your options are to specify `EnvironmentFile=-/etc/environment` in your unit files, or set a `DefaultEnvironment="TZ=whatever"` as specified in the `systemd-system.conf` manpage (I don't think there is currently a `DefaultEnvironmentFile`)

Comment: That is not how you set your TZ, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/323131/setting-timezone-from-terminal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting timezone from terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/323131/setting-timezone-from-terminal)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you did something like

```
TZ=:/etc/localtime
```

This will not however propagate to subshells - and you normal bash shell is a subshell of the wider environment. So you need to do:

```
export TZ=:/etc/localtime
```

Comment: Correct. Neither of these worked, even after a reboot. I need a solution that will work for upstart jobs and systemd units as well as commands invoked via other shells (e.g. sh, dash, ash, etc).

Comment: @AndrewMartin most of those start with clean environments, and usually don't have any common file for setting an environment.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like I will need a multi-faceted solution then.