# Clock offset problem in dual boot with Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10, time, clock

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 in a partition with Windows 10 on my HP Notebook. Initially whenever I would switch between the systems there would be a time offset (Neither Ubuntu nor Windows showed the right time). After using the command `timedatectl set-local-rtc 1`, Windows shows the correct time and Linux shows GMT time instead of local time. Since there are times when the network connection is poor, hence I don't want to rely on the internet synced time. Is there a way in which I can fix my Linux time to local time instead of GMT and not disturb the Windows clock in process?

Results of`timedatectl status` :

[image: Attached is the timedatectl status command's output]

Comment: What time zone are you in?

Comment: There is a comprehensive guide to this problem here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Multiple_Boot_Systems_Time_Conflicts I think all you need to do now is set your time zone in the Ubuntu settings app

Comment: @PonJar My time zone is IST (GMT+5:30).

Comment: @PonJar Also, I have already used the timedatectl command but after using that it only shows correct time in windows but not in Linux. Also, if NTP requires internet then it might not be helpful during times when there are network issues.

Comment: Show us the output of `timedatectl status` as an edit to your question. Have you set your time zone to IST in Linux since getting Windows to show the correct time?

Comment: @PonJar, please find attached the output of ``timedatectl status`` as an edit to this question. The time zone is set to IST since getting Windows to show the right time.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and I it is nowhere clearly mentioned whether the UTC setting works good for Windows 10. Also, since I have a lot of data on my windows, I just want to be sure this method won't interfere with my other system functionalities.

Comment: I guess with any change you make to a system there is an element of risk. Based on the absence of information about problems in Windows the probability is that there are no common issues with making this change. The link provided by @Nmath would have a load of comments if the changes described led to problems.

Comment: I did ``timedatectl set-local-rtc 0`` and seems like both the clocks run at the same time now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the command `timedatectl set-local-rtc 0` and seems like both the clocks run at the same time now.
Thanks to all the comments for the help!

Comment: This one works too: https://askubuntu.com/a/138442/1671974